# Method Not allowed + Get Verb in WebInvoke

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service in which i have a method which return any string.

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="Get", UriTemplate="api/GetData/{name}", ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData(string name);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "Post", UriTemplate = "api/PutData", ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string PutData(string name);
}
```

When i hit service URL(http://localhost:56075/Service.svc/api/GetData/gt). it display me error **"Method Not Allowed"**   Can you please tell me what is the problem..

And web config is as below :

```html
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Hello">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service name="Ajax.Service" behaviorConfiguration="Hello" >
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:56075/Service.svc" binding="webHttpBinding"  contract="Ajax.IService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"></endpoint>

      </service>

    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change line:

> [WebInvoke(Method="Get", UriTemplate="api/GetData/{name}", ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

to

> [WebInvoke(Method="Get", UriTemplate="api/GetData?name={name}", ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

and try again.